# What is wrong with my SQL query SUM group-by

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

Hello i have a sql query and it does not count my one row. which is called Spend, you can see it in the fiddle. what is wrong with my code?
I just need basic table

```
Month  ID GOT SPEND
1      1  100 50
2      1  500 200
1      2  200 50
```

I have created the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3623b1/2

Could you please help me?

Here is the query:

```
select 
    keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, 
    MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), 
    sum(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) as Got, 
    coalesce(Suma, 0) AS Spend, 
    (sum(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) - coalesce(Suma, 0)) Total
from keliones_lapas
    left join (
        select Vairuotas, 
               MONTH(Data_islaidu) as Data_islaidu, 
               sum(Suma) as Suma 
   from islaidos 
   group by Vairuotas, MONTH(Data_islaidu)) islaidos 
   on keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id = islaidos.Vairuotas 
   and MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo) = MONTH(islaidos.Data_islaidu)
group by keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), Suma
order by keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** You are taking already month in your subquery then again using `MONTH` to retrieve from month in the join so it's returning `NULL` and not matching with any month of `keliones_lapas`

```
SELECT 
    keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, 
    MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), 
    SUM(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) AS Got, 
    COALESCE(Suma, 0) AS Spend, 
    (SUM(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) - COALESCE(Suma, 0)) Total
FROM keliones_lapas
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Vairuotas, 
           MONTH(Data_islaidu) AS Data_islaidu, --It's already in MONTH
           SUM(Suma) AS Suma 
   FROM islaidos 
   GROUP BY Vairuotas, MONTH(Data_islaidu)) islaidos 
   ON keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id = islaidos.Vairuotas 
   AND MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo) = Data_islaidu --No need to use MONTH or `vice versa`
GROUP BY keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), Suma
ORDER BY keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo)
```

Comment: You are the best! thanks it worked!! Will it work if i want to add for example the year too?

Comment: Of course, it must work in that case also i.e. `MONTH` or `YEAR` or `DAY` or `any date combination`. For any complication you can leave the message.

Comment: i'm new here, how and where exactly i could leave you a message? :)